# Lottery game, picking unique numbers from 1-42

Tags: c, loops

I was wondering if you could help me out, I'm trying to make a lottery game, with numbers 1-42, and all unique. Here is what I have so far:

```
do
{
    printf("\n\t\tPlease enter number %d (1-42):", i+1);
    scanf("%d", &temp);


    if(temp > 0 && temp < 43)
    {
        for(j = 0; j > 6; j++)
        {
            if(temp == lottoNumbers[j])
            {
                printf("\n\n\t\tNumber already chosen, please choose a new number.\a");
            }
            else
                lottoNumbers[i] = temp;
                i++;
        }
    }
    else
        printf("\n\n\t\tPlease enter a valid number.\a");


}while(i < 6);
```

So I want to take the value in first as a regular integer, first it tests if its in range (that's working), then to check if its already an element of the array, if it is, put it in the array and increment i, the problem is it never seems to increment i and just repeats over and over... can't seem to figure out why, any ideas?

Comment: change j > 6 to j < 6

Comment: That would probably be caused by `i++` not being called in your for loop. You might want to try using a for loop in place of while.

Comment: I've tried it using a for loop but had the same issue, the problem is that its not going into the else in the inner for loop where the array element should be assigned

Comment: I would recommend adding curly brackets around all of your conditional expressions to help you reason about them.  In the code you have above, the indentation does not match up to the semantics.

Comment: regarding this line: `for(j = 0; j > 6; j++)`   Since `j` will never be greater than 6, this loop will never execute.  Perhaps you meant: `for(j = 0; j < 6; j++)`

Comment: A simple answer,  the logic is not correct.  Overall, there seems to be a confusion between `i`, `j` and `temp`.   Suggest inserting comments that say what you are trying to do at each step, Then we would be able to say exactly where the variation is between what your want to do and what the code is actually doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
if(temp > 0 && temp < 43)
{
    for(j = 0; j < i ; j++)
    {
        if(temp == lottoNumbers[j])
        {
            printf("\n\n\t\tNumber already chosen, please choose a new number.\a");
            break;
        }
    }
    if(i == 0 || i == j){//just if(i == j)
        lottoNumbers[i++] = temp;
    }
}
else
    printf("\n\n\t\tPlease enter a valid number.\a");
```

Comment: A-ha! Thank you, I see it now, the else was always being executed inside the loop and i was incrementing to 6 and it was throwing itself out. Thank you!